# Where do I have to push that I get the following format?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, json, npm

I would like to tinker arrays from which I can assemble the following JSON file, so far everything works, I just can't get any further at this point:

```
    var T_nn_IN = document.getElementById('datatablenewname');
    var tabledata_newname_initialname = [];
    var tabledata_newname_newname = [];
    var tabledata_newname_rev = [];
    // var tabledata_newname_IN2 = [];

    $(T_nn_IN).find('> tbody > tr > td').each(function () {
        //tabledata_newname_IN1.push($(this).html())
        if($(this).hasClass("initialname") == true){
            tabledata_newname_initialname.push($(this).html())
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("newname") == true){
            tabledata_newname_newname.push($(this).html())
        }
        if($(this).hasClass("rev") == true){
            tabledata_newname_rev.push($(this).html())

            myJSONtable.push({"Satz.Ursprungsdateien":tabledata_newname_initialname})
            myJSONtable.push({"Satz.NeuerName":tabledata_newname_newname})
            myJSONtable.push({"Satz.Revision":tabledata_newname_rev})
        }
```

Here you can see how it should look after the function has been run:

```
{
    
    "Satz": [
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder1",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder1",
            "Revision": "05"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder2",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder2",
            "Revision": "04"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder3",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder3",
            "Revision": "02"
        },
        {
            "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder4",
            "NeuerName": "placeholder4",
            "Revision": "02"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here you can See what I actually get jet:

```
Satz.Ursprungsdateien: (4) ["placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3", "placeholder4"]

Satz.NeuerName: (4) ["placeholder1", "placeholder2", "placeholder3", "placeholder4"]

Satz.Revision: (4) ["05", "04", "02", "02"]
```

Where or how do I have to push the data so that it looks like it should.

So in the end I want 4 arrays each filled with a Satz.Ursprungsdateien, a Satz.NeuerName and a Satz.Revision.

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you are pushing object in wrong way, you need to create array then push object into that array

Replace these lines

```
    myJSONtable.push({ "Satz.Ursprungsdateien": tabledata_newname_initialname })
    myJSONtable.push({ "Satz.NeuerName": tabledata_newname_newname })
    myJSONtable.push({ "Satz.Revision": tabledata_newname_rev })
```

With this

```
    if(typeof myJSONtable.Satz == 'undefined'){
        myJSONtable.Satz = []
        myJSONtable.Satz.push({
            "Ursprungsdateien": tabledata_newname_initialname, 
            "NeuerName": tabledata_newname_newname, 
            "Revision": tabledata_newname_rev})
    }else{
        myJSONtable.Satz.push({
            "Ursprungsdateien": tabledata_newname_initialname,
            "NeuerName": tabledata_newname_newname,
            "Revision": tabledata_newname_rev
        })
    }
```

**Updated**

Replace this

```
if($(this).hasClass("initialname") == true){
    tabledata_newname_initialname.push($(this).html())
}
if($(this).hasClass("newname") == true){
    tabledata_newname_newname.push($(this).html())
}
if($(this).hasClass("rev") == true){
    tabledata_newname_rev.push($(this).html())

    myJSONtable.push({"Satz.Ursprungsdateien":tabledata_newname_initialname})
    myJSONtable.push({"Satz.NeuerName":tabledata_newname_newname})
    myJSONtable.push({"Satz.Revision":tabledata_newname_rev})
}
```

with

```
var myObj = {}
if ($(this).hasClass("initialname") == true) {
    myObj['Ursprungsdateien'] = $(this).html()
}
if ($(this).hasClass("newname") == true) {
    myObj['NeuerName'] = $(this).html()
}
if ($(this).hasClass("rev") == true) {
    myObj['Revision'] = $(this).html()
}

if (typeof myJSONtable.Satz == 'undefined') {
    myJSONtable.Satz = []
    myJSONtable.push(myObj)
}else{
    myJSONtable.push(myObj)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now have to find a way to break it down to the following edition:

```
{

"Satz": [
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder1",
        "NeuerName": "placeholder1",
        "Revision": "05"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder2",
        "NeuerName": "placeholder2",
        "Revision": "04"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder3",
        "NeuerName": "placeholder3",
        "Revision": "02"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placeholder4",
        "NeuerName": "placeholder4",
        "Revision": "02"
    }
]
```

}

currently it still looks like this:

```
{

"Satz": [
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placholder1"
    },
    {
        "NeuerName": "placholder1"
    },
    {
        "Revision": "05"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placholder2"
    },
    {
        "NeuerName": "placholder2"
    },
    {
        "Revision": "04"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placholder3"
    },
    {
        "NeuerName": "placholder3"
    },
    {
        "Revision": "02"
    },
    {
        "Ursprungsdateien": "placholder4"
    },
    {
        "NeuerName": "placholder4"
    },
    {
        "Revision": "02"
    }
]
```

}